# Nginx Custom Error Page not working

Tags: nginx

My Nginx does not give custom 4x and 5x error pages.My configuration is mentioned below

```
error_page 400 404 /404;
error_page 500 502 504  /service-unavailable;
```

Where `/404` and `/service-unavailable` both urls exists on my site physically.

Full Server Block Configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;# listen port
    server_name  ww.itimes.com ww1.itimes.com;
    root   /iTimesnfs/Nweb/web/itimesV3/public_html;# Document root

    error_page 400 404 /404;
    error_page 500 502 504  /service-unavailable;

    index index.php  index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass fastcgiservers;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        expires 90d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
        access_log   off;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: the file `/404` exists? What exactly does `both urls exists on my site physically` mean?

Comment: Show full server block. Not just a couple of strings.

Comment: Hi I mean both urls http://example.com/404 and http://example.com/service-unavailable exists physically.

Comment: Sure , Alexey I am adding full server block configuration.

Comment: "exists physically" **where**? Please be specific do you mean this is a file: `/iTimesnfs/Nweb/web/itimesV3/public_html/404`?

Comment: No its not a file "/iTimesnfs/Nweb/web/itimesV3/public_html" is document root and "/404" & "/service-unavailable" are link which resolves to php controller/action.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your server block

```
location ~* ^/(400|404|500|502|503|service-unavailable)$ {
  log_not_found off;
  root /path/to/your/docroot;
  internal;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sibin,Thanks for your response. I am not able to understand what this statement will do "location ~* ^/(400|404|500|502|503|service-unavailable)" and how it will work.

Comment: It will set a root dir for all the error pages :)

Comment: Sibin is using a regular expression to capture error codes and messages but I think this could conflict with web sites. For example if I have an online shop with product id 400, then my url could be myshop.com/400 and nginx will intercept and not show product page but wil show error page instead. As an answer I would even downvote :(